# Flightplan in Windows - Host key verification failed

Tags: node.js, windows, ssh

I'm using flightplan to push my website up to a server. It works perfectly fine on my Mac. I tried to get it setup on my Windows computer, and finally got stuck.

First it was rsync, but I fixed that and have it working on windows. Now I'm getting `Host key verification failed.`

The part I can't figure out is that when I ssh in from a shell prompt on windows, I am good to go. It *appears* that I have it pointed appropriately to my `.ssh` directory as well.

Any help would be very appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was because my ssh key on the remote server was in the "deploy" user `.ssh` directory, but not in the root `.ssh` directory. Added my key there and everything was good.